# How to test the convergence of the following series?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sin{\frac{1}{n}}$: The only test I can think of for this one is basic comparison ($\sin{\frac{1}{n}}\le\frac{1}{n}$). But $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots\cdot (2n)\pi^{ n+1}}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots\cdot (2n-1)e^{2n-1}}$: For this one I have no idea how the series actually look like.

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=\color{red}{2}}\frac{\cos{(n\pi)}}{\ln{n}}$: We know $\frac{\cos{(n\pi)}}{\ln{n}}\ge \frac{-1}{n}$. But is $\frac{-1}{n}$ divergent , though $\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.

Comment: $\sin(1/n)\gt \frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: This question consists of three different questions.  I suggest asking one question per post.

Comment: For the 1st one limit comparison test works, as you know $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 }\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Comment: You have probably written the third one wrongly. $\cos\pi=-1$ but $\ln 1=0$ so the first term is $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not encouraged to ask multiple questions in one post; however, since this question is very old, I'll try and answer all three.

For the first series, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} n \sin(1/n)=1$ and $\sin(1/n)>0$, it is equivalent to compare to $\sum_n 1/n$, the divergent harmonic series.

For the second series, the best strategy is to use the Ratio Test:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots\cdot (2n)\cdot(2n+2)\pi^{ n+2}}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n+1)e^{2n+1}}\cdot \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots\cdot (2n-1)e^{2n-1}}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots\cdot (2n)\pi^{ n+1}}\right|
$$
$$
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(2n+2)\pi}{(2n+1)e^{2}}\right|=\frac{\pi}{e^2}<1
$$So the series converges.

For the third series, an earlier version had the starting index at $n=1$, which caused division by zero. However, if we reindex to start at $n=2$, since $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$ we could use the Alternating Series Test. Then since $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/\ln(n)=0$, and since $\ln(n)$ is positive and increasing, we conclude the series converges.